# ¿Cómo redireccionar en .htaccess según el idioma del navegador?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirección

Estoy creando una web multiidioma en Wordpress implementada con 3 instalaciones independientes, una en el directorio "EN", otra en el directorio "ES" y otra en el directorio "FR", todos directorios en el mismo nivel en la raíz. Y cada una es midominio.com/en o midominio.com/fr o midominio.com/es. Las 3 webs tienes que ser accesibles en todos los idiomas, con lo que no puede haber redirecciones automáticas.

El único caso en el que quiero redirección automatica es cuando se pide la raíz del dominio "midominio.com". Quisiera saber el código del .htaccess para conseguir esto. Las condiciones son:

---

Activarse SOLO cuando alguien pida el dominio raíz limpio “midominio.com” y según estas reglas:

-Si el idioma del navegador es ES --> redirige a "midominio.com/es"

-Sino, si el idioma es FR --> redirige a "midominio.com/fr"

-Sino (en cualquier otro caso) --> redirige al idioma por defecto que es EN: "midominio.com/en".

---

Pero si alguien pide ya con código de idioma no tiene que activarse (p.ej. midominio.com/es/xxx). Solo si se pide el dominio limpio. Creo q es la única forma de que no haya redirecciones en páginas, para que cualquier página en cualquier idioma sea accesible (sino Google no podría encontrarla si redirecciona).

Solo redirecciona la raíz que no es ninguna página en sí, y redireccionará a la raíz del idioma correspondiente, que será la home de esa web.

(Si estoy diciendo alguna tontería, agradecería si alguien me lo dice! :P).

Muchas gracias y un saludo!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Qués has intentado/investigado? Es necesario que muestres tu código, o lo que has investigado al respecto. Tu pregunta parece del tipo: *hagan esto por mi*, y esa no es la idea del sitio. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour] para que comprendas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para detectar que sólo se pide el dominio principal usamos:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/?)$ [NC]
```

- uri vacío o sólo `/`

para detectar el idioma usamos:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^(es|en|fr).*$ [NC]
```

- donde `es` `en` y `fr` son los códigos de idioma, el `^` significa desde el principio así que toma el principal o preferido, En este ejemplo `|` significa `or` así que la regla va a matchear español, inglés o francés.
- español puede venir como `es` o `es-AR` por si hay variaciones locales de contenidos

---

```
%{HTTP:Accept-language}
```

Devuelve el contenido de [la cabecera HTTP Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) que permite negociar el contenido según las preferencias del usuario o el idioma de la interfaz de usuario del navegador que a su vez puede copiar esta preferencia del idioma de la interfaz de usuario del sistema operativo.

Es una lista separada por `,` donde cada ítem representa el idioma (en: english) y, si corresponde o está disponible, la variación local separada con un `-` ( en-US : english united states ). La variación local es por si hay diferentes formas de expresar el contenido/traducciones, por lo general es útil para setear otros tipos de opciones visuales como formatos de fechas, separador de decimales, etc.

Si hay mas de un ítem ademas del principal por lo general se incluye [un valor de calificación de calidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/quality_values) (`;q=[0-1]`) que indica el peso o el orden de prioridad de los ítems con un valor que va entre 0 y 1 inclusives.

En el ejemplo:

```
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,fr-CA;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,de-DE;q=0.5,de;q=0.4
```

- `en-US` ( Inglés de Estados Unidos de América ) es el principal preferido
- `en` ( Inglés genérico ) es la alternativa con mayor preferencia por que tiene un valor `q` de `0.9`
- `es` ( Español genérico ) es la alternativa con segundo mayor preferencia ( `q=0.8` )
- `fr-CA` ( Francés de Canadá ) va tercero
- `fr` ( Francés genérico ) cuarto
- `de-DE` ( Alemán de Alemania ) quinto
- `de` ( Alemán genérico ) al final por su menor valor de preferencia

En cada ejemplo se incluye el valor de `%{HTTP:Accept-language}` en un comentario para que puedas ver cómo es el matching. Esta cabecera en php la podes ver y/o interpretar ( para cambiar formatos de números o fechas en las variaciones locales por ejemplo ) a través del array `$_SERVER[]`, por ejemplo:

`public/es/index.php`

```
<h1>ES</h1>
<p>cabecera de idiomas: <?php print_r( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] );?></p>
<p>url pedida original: <?php print_r( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );?></p>
<p>el resto de variables para debug</p>
<pre>
<?php print_r( $_SERVER  ); ?>
</pre>
```

Volviendo al `.htaccess`, para matchear idiomas no principales u opcionales/alternativos buscamos con comodines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^.*(es).*$ [NC]
```

- tener en cuenta el orden para los alternativos ( interpretar el `q` en esta fase es medio engorroso así que lo hacemos por orden de reglas )

Para manejar los 404 del directorio raíz usamos el siguiente bloque:

```
# si no es un archivo y
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# si no es un directorio
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# ir al english con lo se que pide y que wp se maneje
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,NE]
```

Esto permite evitar un 404 pasandole la cadena pedida al wordpress en `en` y que esa instalación se encargue de realizar una redirección soft o muestre una página de `404` personalizada. Un ejemplo sería que pidan `www.midominio.mitld/index.php` y no tengas uno en el raíz ( `!-f` = no es un filename ), eso lo llevaría a `www.midominio.mitld/en/index.php`

Finalmente redirigimos a `/en` para todos los otros casos.

Tener en cuenta que cada regla que encuentra un match realiza la redirección ( no sigue procesando ) así que si bien el último caso toma el idioma inglés, también esta bueno ponerlo explícito al principio para evitar procesar reglas de mas.

```
# Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# si el uri ya contiene un idioma x ej: /es/
# o es una carpeta x ej: /es
# o es un archivo x ej: /robots.txt
# dejar de procesar reglas
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(en|es|fr)/.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [END]

# el uri está vacío: www.midominio.mitld o
# el uri es "/" : www.midominio.mitld/
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/?)$ [NC]

# inglés está como principal
# en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,fr-CA;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,de-DE;q=0.5,de;q=0.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^(en).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) en/ [L,R,NE]

# español está como principal
# es,fr-CA;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^(es).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) es/ [L,R,NE]

# francés está como principal:
# fr-CA,fr;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.5,es;q=0.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^(fr).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) fr/ [L,R,NE]

# español está como alternativo:
# de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6,fr-CA;q=0.5,fr;q=0.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^.*(es).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) es/ [L,R,NE]

# francés está como alternativo:
# de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6,fr-CA;q=0.5,fr;q=0.4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^.*(fr).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) fr/ [L,R,NE]

# si no es un archivo y
# si no es un directorio
# ir al english con lo se que pide y que wp se maneje
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,NE]

# finalmente para todo lo demás ir al english
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) en/ [L,R,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: -El primer bloque de "# inglés está como principal" ¿no sobraría? Siendo que es lo de por defecto. Tanto si tienes el navegador en italiano como en inglés, ya el último código maneja el caso, ¿no? Del mismo modo que no hay bloque para cada idioma (italiano, ruso, etc.) porque todos cogen el de por defecto del final. 
-¿El francés no tiene alternativo? 
-¿Me puedes decir qué hace el bloque de “si no es un archivo y si no es un directorio”?
-Y los comentarios tipo: 
# en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,fr-CA;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,de-DE;q=0.5,de;q=0.4
¿Qué significan?

Comment: editado para mayor claridad, el primer bloque de inglés como principal es para terminar de procesar las reglas en ese punto, incluido el francés alternativo ( es igual al español pero cambia el matching a `fr` ) el ante último bloque permite redirigir los 404 del raíz al wordpress en `/en` ( te ahorras una pagina 404 custom ) los comentarios son el valor de la cabecera, se incluye código php para verla

Comment: Funciona perfecto. La comprobación “uri vacío o solo /” ¿Es necesaria porque el .htaccess en raíz se ejecuta siempre? Pensaba que se ejecutaría solo al pedir la raíz, como un index.php y que no haría falta esa comprobación. ¿Es ineficiente que se ejecute en todas las peticiones a la web aunque sean /es/xxx o /fr/xxx? Cada vez que un usuario navegue, haga clics, etc. ¿se estará ejecutando? Cuando solo debería ejecutarse si se pide la raíz, ya que cualquier otro caso no hará nada. ¿Hay alguna opción para que solo se ejecute al pedir raíz? ¿O quizá sería más eficiente hacerlo en un index.php?

Comment: se ejecuta siempre y vale para todas las subcarpetas, para mayor eficiencia habría que moverlo a una seccion `<Directory>` en el server.conf ( `httpd.conf`, `default.conf`, `000-default.conf` o el archivo personalizado de configuración del dominio que tu distribución use ) si no tenes acceso al servidor se puede poner una regla al principio que deje de procesar si ya tiene un fragmento `/en/` `/es/` o `/fr/`

Comment: El .htaccess funciona perfecto. 
¿Recomendarías pues hacerlo con un index.php para que así solo se ejecute el código al pedir el dominio raíz? En ese caso, ¿Sabes algún tutorial para hacer lo mismo en PHP?

Comment: 1/ . edité para que tenga un corte prematuro en caso de ya existir la url como archivo/carpeta o incluir un fragmento de idioma, de hacer una recomendación lo ideal sería ( siempre y cuando los sitios no difieran mas que en el contenido ) usar un plugin de traducciones que use la url onda [polylang](https://polylang.pro/downloads/polylang/) ( la versión free por lo general sirve ) o [wpml](https://wpml.org/) ( sólo de pago ) que de paso manejan la relación entre diferentes idiomas via [`hreflang`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en).

Comment: 2/ . Si querés implementarlo por `index.php` como alternativa o para comparar rendimiento armate otra pregunta y lo desarrollamos ahí ( así queda referencia a futuro para otra persona con la misma inquietud ) en principio sería leer la cabecera que viene en `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` e interpretarla como string haciendo un switch case o varios if