# ¿Cómo redireccionar en PHP según el idioma del navegador?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirección

La idea es crear una redirección automática según el idioma del navegador, cuando se pide la raíz del dominio "midominio.com", hacia el directorio "EN", o directorio "ES" o directorio "FR", todos directorios en el mismo nivel en la raíz (midominio.com/en o midominio.com/fr o midominio.com/es). Las 3 webs tienes que ser accesibles en todos los idiomas, con lo que no puede haber redirecciones automáticas entre ellas. El PHP estará ubicado en la raíz del dominio y por tanto, solo se ejecutará si alguien pide el dominio limpio.

A raíz de la misma cuestión planteada en [¿Cómo redireccionar en .htaccess según el idioma del navegador?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352093/c%c3%b3mo-redireccionar-en-htaccess-seg%c3%ban-el-idioma-del-navegador) pero para hacerlo en .htaccess [SOLUCIÓN INCLUÍDA] se comenta la posibilidad de que en PHP sea más eficiente, por eso se abre esta nueva consulta para solucionar lo mismo en PHP.

Las condiciones son:

---

Activarse SOLO cuando alguien pida el dominio raíz limpio “midominio.com” (al ser un PHP ubicado en la raíz ya solo se ejecutará en ese caso) y según estas reglas:

-Si el idioma del navegador es ES --> redirige a "midominio.com/es"

-Sino, si el idioma es FR --> redirige a "midominio.com/fr"

-Sino (en cualquier otro caso) --> redirige al idioma por defecto que es EN: "midominio.com/en".

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

versión corta:

```
<?php
// si no existe el header asumimos english
// opcionalmente aquí podes leer una cookie que haga override
$accept_languaje = !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] ) ?
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] : 'en';

// idioma principal en las dos primeras letras
$main_languaje = substr ( $accept_languaje, 0 , 2 );

// idioma principal ( no hace falta break debido al exit )
switch ( $main_languaje ) :
  case 'en' :
  exit( header( "Location: http://www.midominio.mitld/en" ) );
  case 'fr' :
  exit( header( "Location: http://www.midominio.mitld/fr" ) );
  case 'es' :
  exit( header( "Location: http://www.midominio.mitld/es" ) );
endswitch;

// el orden de los if da preferencia para los idiomas alternativos
if ( false !== strpos( $accept_languaje, 'en' ) ) {
  exit( header( "Location: http://www.midominio.mitld/en" ) );
}

if ( false !== strpos( $accept_languaje, 'fr' ) ) {
  exit( header( "Location: http://www.midominio.mitld/fr" ) );
}

if ( false !== strpos( $accept_languaje, 'es' ) ) {
  exit( header( "Location: http://www.midominio.mitld/es" ) );
}

// finalmente al englisch
exit( header( "Location: http://www.midominio.mitld/en" ) );
```

---

versión extendida para debug:

```
<?php
$dominio_base = 'http://www.midominio.mitld';
$redirection = '';
// si no existe el header asumimos english
$accept_languaje = !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] ) ?
  $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] : 'en';
// idioma principal en las dos primeras letras
$main_languaje = substr ( $accept_languaje, 0 , 2 );
switch ( $main_languaje ) :
  # inglés está como principal
  # en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,fr-CA;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,de-DE;q=0.5,de;q=0.4
  case 'en' :
  $redirection = '/en';
  break;
  # español está como principal
  # es,fr-CA;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.4
  case 'es' :
  $redirection = '/es';
  break;
  # francés está como principal:
  # fr-CA,fr;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.5,es;q=0.4
  case 'fr' :
  $redirection = '/fr';
  break;
  # dejamos limpio para poder detectar idiomas alternativos
  default:
  $redirection = '';
endswitch;

// si aún no está definido buscamos alternativos ( básico sin considerar el q )
// el orden de los if da preferencia
if ( '' === $redirection && false !== strpos( $accept_languaje, 'en' ) ) {
  $redirection = '/en';
}
if ( '' === $redirection && false !== strpos( $accept_languaje, 'fr' ) ) {
  $redirection = '/fr';
}
if ( '' === $redirection && false !== strpos( $accept_languaje, 'es' ) ) {
  $redirection = '/es';
}
// si aún no se encuentra alternativa: default a english
$redirection = '' === $redirection ? '/en' : $redirection;

// comentar para debug
// terminar script devolviendo el header que redirige
exit( header( "Location: {$dominio_base}{$redirection}" ) );

?>
<h1>MAIN</h1>
<p>languaje header:<?php print_r( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] );?></p>
<p>requested uri: <?php print_r( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );?></p>
<p>redirection: <?php echo $redirection; ?></p>
<p>header: <?php echo "Location: {$dominio_base}{$redirection}"; ?></p>
<pre>
  <?php print_r( $_SERVER  ); ?>
</pre>
```

---

- en ambos casos el `.htaccess` del raíz debería considerar los 404
- la mayoría de los navegadores aceptan una ruta relativa onda `"Location: /fr"` pero para abarcar lo mas posible se utiliza la url completa con el protocolo + dominino ( `"Location: http://www.midominio.mitld/fr"` )

Comment: Sobre este código (versión corta) que usé hace un tiempo,… he estado probando con idiomas alternativos, por ejemplo en Chrome, Idiomas = Italiano + Español. Según el código, los “if” de los idiomas alternativos tendría que redireccionar a /es pero muestra /en que es la de por defecto. 
En cambio en Firefox, idiomas = italiano y español sí que lleva correctamente a /es. 
¿Alguna idea de por qué puede ocurrir eso en Chrome?

Comment: si no existe el header `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` ( el navegador no lo envía o se pierde entre proxy, balancers u otra cuestión en el medio ) se predetermina `'en'` en la línea `$accept_languaje = !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] ) ?
  $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] : 'en';`

Comment: versión compacta para php 7+ `$accept_languaje = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] ?? 'en';` ( WP core todavía da soporte a php 5.6 )

Comment: Pero he hecho varias pruebas solo cambiando en Chrome los idiomas instalados y no creo que sea el caso de que no exista el header no? Pues el resto de pruebas funciona (p.ej. si idioma principal de Chrome es español sí redirecciona a /es). Solo es cuando el  idioma principal he puesto italiano y como 2º el español, que entiendo que seria un alternativo y debería entrar en ese “if” y mostrar /es (como sí ha pasado en Firefox probando lo mismo). ¿Y con lo de “para php7+” quieres decir que debería actualizar el código? ¿Sólo sería cambiar las 2 primeras líneas por esta compacta? ¿El resto igual?

Comment: 1/ la versión compacta es mas "legible" se llama operador de [coalescencia](https://dle.rae.es/coalescencia) y lo que hace es lo mismo que la version extendida: si el header no existe o es nulo asignar el valor a la derecha del `??` en este caso `en`, caso contrario usar el valor de la variable testeada ( en este caso el header ). Es util para evitar escribir 2 ifs o usar el `if not empty` de la expresión/operador ternario. Como efecto secundarios: hace mas rápido identificar cambios en control de versiones y evita bugs del tipo copy paste edit ( cuando cambia la variable a testear )

Comment: 2/ para testear chrome, en settings -> preferred languages, usar el menu de los `...` para ordenar la preferencia en idiomas/languages instalados. con f12 abris el inspector vas a la pestaña de red y al seleccionar la petición en el detalle de `request headers` vas a ver la lista ordenada de languages algo tipo `accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,fr-CA;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,es-AR;q=0.5,de-DE;q=0.4,de;q=0.3`. Si sospechas que el header se pierde en algun lugar probá con la versión de debug en un `test_lang.php`

Comment: Chrome se dejaba idiomas alternativos en la cabecera pero he visto que era porque iba en incógnito,… en Chrome normal ya manda bien todos los idiomas alternativos y el código funciona como esperaba :)
Una pregunta: entiendo que si idioma principal no es ninguno de los 3 que miramos, p.ej. es italiano, es cuando se ejecutan los 3 ifs. Y en ese caso importa el orden: si tienes como alternativos español e inglés, va a /en porque el if va primero, verdad? Preferiría que si tienes como alternativo el español, vaya a /ES. Entonces solo debería poner ese if primero verdad?

Comment: si, cuando la cabecera viene completa `accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,fr-CA; ....etc` cada preferencia viene junto a un número que indica la prioridad que por lo general está ordenado de mas preferente a menos preferente, para evitar tener que chequear el "orden de preferencia" los if buscan substring en el "orden" que priorizamos (nosotros no el navegador).

Comment: para predeterminar español pondría `??'es'` al principio y luego mover el if que testea el substring `es` antes de los otros ifs. el último redirect está por si la cabecera es válida pero no contiene alternativas ni para el switch ni para los ifs

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con `locale_accept_from_http()`, y haces la redirección que desees. Para evitar un bucle, que sólo se ejecute este código en el caso que no te encuentres dentro de una página /es o /en.

```
$idioma = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

if ($idioma = 'es_ES') {
    header('Location: https://midominio.com/es');
    exit;
}

if ($idioma = 'fr_FR') {
    header('Location: https://midominio.com/fr');
    exit;
}

if ($idioma = 'en_GB') {
    header('Location: https://midominio.com/en');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: ¿Se podría coger solo 2 letras del código idioma? Tiene que valer para cualquier es_xx, y lo mismo para fr_xx o en_xx. De hecho inglés sería el de por defecto para cualquier idioma que no sea español o francés (imagino que será algo así como el último bloque poner la redirección directamente?).

Comment: No se puede poner sólo 2 letras, podrías hacer una función que te agrupe los idiomas es_XX en 'es' y los inglés lo mismo en_XX en 'en'.